# using Powershell to call asynchronous web methods on a web service

Tags: web-services, powershell

I'm using PowerShell V2 and trying to find an example of using a web service proxy to call an asynchronous web method:

Here is the code I have so far:

```
$Uri = "http://localhost/mywebservice.asmx?wsdl" 

$proxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $Uri -UseDefaultCredential
```

The web services has the following methods
**BeginFoo** 
**EndFoo** 
**FooAsync**
**FooCompleted**

Hopefully this makes sense

Answer (score 6):

Here's an example of using BeginInvoke/EndInvoke.  Run `$ar | Get-Member` to see what other methods and properties are available to you on the IAsyncResult object.

```
PS> $zip = New-WebServiceProxy -uri http://www.webservicex.net/uszip.asmx?WSDL
PS> $ar = $zip.BeginGetInfoByAreaCode("970", $null, $null)

... other PS script ...

# Now join the async work back to the PowerShell thread, wait for completion
# and grab the result. WaitOne returns false on timeout, true if signaled.
PS> $ar.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne([timespan]'0:0:5')
True
PS> $ar.IsCompleted
True
PS> $res = $zip.EndGetInfoByAreaCode($ar)
PS> $res.Table


CITY      : Whitewater
STATE     : CO
ZIP       : 81527
AREA_CODE : 970
TIME_ZONE : M

CITY      : Wiggins
STATE     : CO
ZIP       : 80654
AREA_CODE : 970
TIME_ZONE : M
```

Comment: Thanks Keith I will test this out in the morning