# How to call a collection of REST APIs concurrently in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to load test my RESTful web server, and would like to run a collection of 20 HTTP requests as a collection, with multiple such collections running simultaneously.I tried using `Postman` but it doesn't have a feature to run multiple instances of collections concurrently. Also, was trying `jmeter by Apache` but it gives me lots of errors.

I am wondering if I could just write a `powershell` script to do this.

Comment: This looks like an example of calling  web services async and capturing their eventual completion. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11111490/using-powershell-to-call-asynchronous-web-methods-on-a-web-service

Comment: Can you provide a sample of a single request, like method/headers/body?